# Python type hint should take any class that implements a protocol, but should return the class itself

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a function `Transfer()` that takes a class from a type defined by a protocol, but want its return type hint to be specifically the same from the class it got as an input. How do I accomplish this?

Example code:

```
class Human:
  pass

# Implement protocol that will be followed by any class that has property `owner`
class Pet(Protocol):
  owner: Human

bob = Human()
alice = Human()

# Cat is a Pet, but has an extra method `meow()`
class Cat:
  owner =  bob

  def meow(self):
    print("meow")

# Dog is a Pet, but has an extra method `woof()`
class Dog:
  owner = bob

  def woof(self):
    print("woof")

def Transfer(pet: Pet):
  pet.owner = alice
  return pet

bob_dog = Dog()
bob_cat = Cat()

# type hint works fine
bob_dog.woof()
bob_cat.meow()

alice_dog = Transfer(bob_dog)
alice_cat = Transfer(bob_cat)

# Transfer() return type is automatically set to `Pet`, but should be `Dog` and `Cat`
# type hint doesn't work
alice_dog.woof()
alice_cat.meow()
```

Comment: Use [generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics)?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, and for answering. I indeed don't know about generics, but they seem to be helpful. Using them like this sorta solves the problem, but I lose the information about the Type being a `Pet`. How would you do it otherwise?
```T = TypeVar('T')
def Transfer(pet: T) -> T:
  pet.owner = alice
  return pet```

Comment: Use a _bound_ `TypeVar`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar.

Comment: Thanks!!!! If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1):

As jonrsharpe suggested, this will solve the problem

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Pet)
def Transfer(pet: T) -> T:
  pet.owner = alice
  return pet
```